# How to put a href in google sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, concatenation, href, google-sheets-formula

I have $92.00 in cell A2 and https://google.com in B2. I want to make a formula so I get following in C2. Can someone please help. I know hyperlink function but I really need exactly same as below in my C2 cell

`<a href="https://google.com/">$92.00</a>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href=",char(34),B2,"/",char(34),"<",text(A2,"$00.00"),"/a>")
```

char(34) is a single quote.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
="<a href="&CHAR(34)&B2&"/"&CHAR(34)&"<"&TEXT(A2, "$00.00")&"/a>"
```

or just:

```
="<a href="""&B2&"/""<"&TEXT(A2; "$00.00")&"/a>"
```